# Panadas Condition on Dataframe returns TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, pandas-apply

I'm working on a DataFrame using pandas and I need to add a new column based on some conditions.

My DataFrame is:

```
discount   tax   total   subtotal   productid
  3         0     20       13        002
  10        3     106      94        003
  46.49     6     21       20        004
```

I need to apply some conditions while adding a new column named as **Class** to the DataFrame.

Conditions are as follows:
IF `discount > 20 &  total > 100 & tax == 0` then **Class** should be **1**
otherwise it should be **0**

Here's how I have tried:

```
def conditions(s):
    if (s['discount'] > 20) and (s['tax'] == 0) and (s['total'] > 100):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df_full['Class'] = df_full.apply(conditions, axis=1)
```

But it returns an error as:

> TypeError: ("'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'", 'occurred at index 18')

How can I solve this issue?

help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest create boolean mask and cast to `int`, `True`s are `1`s and `False`s are `0`s, also change `and` to `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
print (df_full)
   discount  tax  total  subtotal productid
0      3.00    0     20        13       002
1     40.00    0    106        94       003
2     46.49    6     21        20       004
```

You can also check all non numeric values:

```
print(df_full[pd.to_numeric(df_full['discount'], errors='coerce').isnull()]

#for convert to numeric - non numeric are convert to `NaN`s
df_full['discount'] = pd.to_numeric(df_full['discount'], errors='coerce')
```

---

```
df_full['Class'] = ((df_full['discount'] > 20) & 
                    (df_full['tax'] == 0) & 
                    (df_full['total'] > 100)).astype(int)
print (df_full)
   discount  tax  total  subtotal productid  Class
0      3.00    0     20        13       002      0
1     40.00    0    106        94       003      1
2     46.49    6     21        20       004      0
```

Comment: Hi @jezreal, now it returns another error as `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: I think need `df_full['discount'] = df_full['discount'].astype(float)` before.

Comment: `ValueError: Unable to parse string "Discount > 20" at position 18`

Comment: @AbdulRehman - It seems some non numeric values, one possible solution is `df_full['discount'] = pd.to_numeric(df_full['discount'], errors='coerce')`